# Handling multiple forms in the same php file

Tags: php, forms

I have a php file that has 3 forms inside and some insert queries and i separate them with if(isset()) so they are not displayed if a variable is not present. I have a problem and i declare a variable after the first form and when i use the second form the variable dissapears and returns as null. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking without any code example...

Comment: if you want previous form value you need to store it in session to keep first form value  if(isset($_POST['first_form_submit'])) { $_SESSION['first_form']=$_POST; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After page load declared variable is not there so use **session**

if you want first form value you need to store it in session to keep first form value

```
if(isset($_POST['first_form_submit'])) { $_SESSION['first_form']=$_POST; }
```

Note : *Don't forgot to start he session_start(); on page very top.*

**Update 1:**

You need email only means do like this

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email']; }
```

Later access it like this `$email = $_SESSION['email'];`

Comment: For example if i need from the first form the $_POST['email'] the code will be : 

if(isset($_POST['email'])) { $_SESSION['email']=$_POST; } 
if yes how do i use it after? for example if i want to declare it as a variable $email = $_POST['email'] ??

Comment: you need email only means do like this  if(isset($_POST['email'])) { $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email']; }  later access it like this $email = $_SESSION['email'];

Comment: it returns Undefined variable: SESSION

Comment: you need to start the session

Comment: wherever your using session variable you need to start the session on page top . session_start();

Comment: i have included the connect.php in the php file and at the end of connect.php there is session_start. Does that count?

Comment: you need to session_start(); only once

Comment: if you started session_start(); on included file means it's enough .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144124/discussion-between-jyothi-and-nikosl24).

Comment: glad to help you @NikosL24